# How to save data from MQTT subscribing to all topics

Tags: java, mqtt

I am using java processing to get sensors data from Arduino and save them into MySql database by using MQTT protocol. I succeed to publish data to my topics

- home/temperature
- home/humidity

and subscribe to all topics

- home/#

I received all the messages. Now I want to save these value into database.

My question is:

How to get the appropriate data and save it according to its topic (home/temperature & home/humidity)?
thank you

this is my code:

```
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;  
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
  import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
  import de.bezier.data.sql.*;
 import processing.serial.*;
  import java.util.regex.*;
  Serial myPort;
  String value;
    String broker;
   String topic;
  String topic1;
  String topic2;
  String payloadtemp;
   String payloadhum;
   MqttClient myClient;
    MySQL DB; 
    String tempsensor_ID;
     String humsensor_ID;
     MqttMessage messagetemp ; 
     MqttMessage messagehum ; 

     void setup()  
        {  
     String portlisten= Serial.list()[0];
     myPort = new Serial( this, portlisten, 115200 );
    broker   = "tcp://192.192.191.198:1883";//;
     topic = "home/#";
    topic1="home/temperatureValue" ;  
     topic2= "home/HumidityValue";
     tempsensor_ID="temp_ID";
      humsensor_ID="hum_ID";
      String user = "root";
      String pass = "";
      String database = "iot";
      DB= new MySQL(this, "localhost", database , user , pass);


          } 
       void draw(){

       if (myPort.available() > 0 ) {
        value = myPort.readString();
        String tempdata = trim(value);
         String humdata=trim(value);
            String patterntemp= "Temperature:";
           String patterntempunit="C";
            String patternhum="Humidity:";
               String patternhumunit="%";
            Pattern ptemp= Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(patterntemp) + "             (.*?)" + Pattern.quote(patterntempunit));
         Matcher mtemp= ptemp.matcher(tempdata);
             while(mtemp.find()){
            tempdata=mtemp.group(1);
              payloadtemp=tempdata;

          }

         Pattern phum= Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(patternhum) + "(.*?)" +               Pattern.quote(patternhumunit));
          Matcher mhum= phum.matcher(humdata);
           while(mhum.find()){
           humdata=mhum.group(1);
               payloadhum=humdata;

                }

              try {  
          myClient = new MqttClient(broker, MqttClient.generateClientId());        
     myClient.connect();        
            messagetemp = new MqttMessage((" " + payloadtemp).getBytes());  
            messagehum = new MqttMessage((" " + payloadhum).getBytes());  



             if(payloadtemp!=(null) & payloadhum!=(null)){

                 myClient.publish(topic1, messagetemp);  
                  myClient.subscribe(topic1); 

                       myClient.publish(topic2, messagehum);  
                     myClient.subscribe(topic2);          


          //myClient.subscribe(topic); //wildcard (topic) used when  subscribing to topics but not allowed when publishing a msg
                       }

                if ( DB.connect() )
               {
               myClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                  @Override
                public void messageArrived(String arg0, MqttMessage arg1) {

                     String msgrec= new String(arg1.getPayload());

                        println("RESULT " + arg0 + " - " + msgrec + " ");


                    throw new RuntimeException();

                            }

                        @Override
                     public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {


                           println("DELIVERY " + arg0);

                           throw new RuntimeException();
                               }

                          @Override
                      public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
                           throw new RuntimeException();
                         }
                          });


                           if(payloadtemp!=(null) & payloadhum!=(null)){


                     /*DB.execute("INSERT INTO `temperature`(`idsensor`,`temperaturevalue`) VALUES ('"+tempsensor_ID+ "','" +      messageReceived(topic1,messagetemp.getPayload()) + "');");
                    DB.execute("INSERT INTO `light`(`idsensor`,`lightvalue`) VALUES ('"+lightsensor_ID+ "','" +   messageReceived(topic2,messagehum.getPayload())+ "');");
                    */
                    }
                    }
                  else
                   {
                println("Error in the connection :-( ");
                      }  
                                 }
                        catch(MqttException mex) {  

                      System.out.println("Error: "+mex.getMessage());  
                            mex.printStackTrace();  
                     } 
                           }

                              }
```

Comment: messageArrived has two parameters one is topic and other is message.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are implementing a PAHO client....

then you need to use the parameter in the messageArrived callback to check wich topic are you getting informed about...

```
client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {

      @Override
      public void messageArrived(String topicInforming, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            subscriptionMessageCallback.onNewMessage(mqttMessage.toString());
      }
   ....
```

in this snippet **topicInforming** is telling you if you are getting a message abpout temperature or humidity,

for the DB you will need a connector to handle the insert transactions...

you need to define if every message should be in the same table or not, is up to you and depends about how the architecture looks like

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just used this code but I have same confuse. I created a client `client = new MqttClient (broker, MattClient.generateClientId())`, next I create 2 messages (`msgtemp= new MqttMessage("temp" + payloadtemp).getBytes())` and `msghum`), after I published (`client.publish("home/temp",msgtemp`) and `client.publish("home/hum",msghum)`. I subscribed (`client.subscribe("home/#")`). My question is it correct the use of messageArrived? `messageReceived(topic,msgtemp.getPayload())` and `messageReceived(topic,mesghum.getPayload())`

Comment: Did you set the callback? ?

Comment: Now, I set the callback, but when I logged the arrived message, I get only the first one ( temperature). Shoud I make a code to verify if arrived topicinformation = topic 1 or topic 2)?? Another note, I get all the sensors data in the same msg from arduino, so it is me who split the received arduino msg and publish them seperately

Comment: But if you are subscribing to ***home/#*** then you have to have a problem with the humidity part....

Comment: even when I subscribed to each topic separately, I still receive the first payload

Comment: I think the problem is by the arduino side

Comment: I don't think it is arduino problem because when I subscribed from command prompt I can see all the received msg. I have a question. Should I use a different client for each data (temperature & humidity)? I mean should I create 2     `myClient = new MqttClient(broker, MqttClient.generateClientId()); ` ??

Comment: Try subscribing to temperature and humidity... instead of the wild card # ... and tell me if you are able to get the data

Comment: I tried it but it is the same problem. I didn't know why

Comment: I edit my question and put my code. can you take a look please